# Retrieve loaded bash profile after ~/.bash_profile deleted

Tags: bash, shell

I was working with a program and it deleted my .bash_profile, which I unfortunately haven't backed up for several months. I however, have one terminal open that I am not going to close which has the file loaded in.

Is there any possible way I can "export" the loaded bash aliases etc from the current terminal?

Answer (score 5):

```
alias > my_aliases
```

can give you some aliases back, but if you have hundreds, you probably want to use `comm(1)` to identify which ones are in another file.

Answer (score 5):

```
declare
```

will dump out all variables and functions in your current shell.  (So will `set`.)

Answer (score 3):

You can get at least some of it with the `env` command:

```
env >template_bash_profile
```

And then work from that.